# Disabling an IP based access to my Nginx site

Tags: tls, webserver, dns, nginx

I do not want people to be able to access my Nginx site, unless it is through the domain name. I have a Flash instance running that controls the requests. Anyways I have used this command,

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}
```

This does block connections correctly, but if someone makes a request from `https://[myipaddress]` then it still takes them to my flask instance.

How do I totally block them from making requests from the IP and only allow traffic from the domain name? Is this even possible?

Comment: Have you tried the `server_name` directive?  https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Comment: Also, port 80 is very unlikely to be used by TLS / HTTPS.  That's port 443.

Comment: When the client sends a "Host: domain" header it means it's accessed by domain name. Maybe use a .htaccess file?

Comment: @zomega The original poster is using Nginx to reverse proxy a Python Flask application; `.htaccess` is an Apache only thing.